# For loop using two variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists, one of which a set of row numbers and another that is file paths. I need to create a loop which will create new dataframes for each file path with the row number I specify.

I have script which creates the new dataframes however I am stuck on the loop.

```
MYLIST = [42, 50, 52, 59, 60, 62] 

PATH = '/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/rt35'

for X,Y in PATH, MYLIST
    df= pd.read_csv(X,
                 index_col= False,
                 header=None,
                 nrows=max(my_list) + 1).loc[Y]
```

The list and path here are just a single example of each.

```
  File "/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/Pandas to createxyt.py", line 17, in <module>
    for X,Y in PATH, MYLIST:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here is the error message I'm getting.
The MYLIST variables will be different for each PATH but in the correct order within each list.

Comment: You can use `zip` and `os.listdir`: `for X,Y in zip(os.listdir(PATH), MYLIST):`.

Comment: `PATH` is *not* a sequence of file paths; it's a string.  You still need to do the work to interpret that string as a path to multiple files.

Comment: I've tried zip(PATH,MYLIST), however I'm still getting the same ValueError as before.

Comment: @mattp Did my answer work for you? If so can you check it. Thanks!

Comment: @mattp if my answer worked for you can you checkmark it.

Answer (score 0):

You can something along the lines of:

```py
arr1 = [[1,3],[1,7],[3,8]]

for first,second in arr1:
    print(first)
    print(second)
```

which returns

```
1
3
1
7
3
8
```

Although this has a nested array. You could try to put them together in an array using for loops.

Comment: Does this make sense

Comment: Can you check my answer if it worked for you? Thanks!